# What are the 16 impurities (ashuddhi) in a human body?

Tags: shiva, body

I came across in Lord Shiva context, where Narada muni told Mata Parvati to get rid of 16 toxicities and purify yourself, can somebody please throw light upon this concept?

**Source:** 
Devon Ke Dev Mahadev-Chapter 4 Episode 162 at 7:00
Where Narad Muni helps Parvati to get rid of 16 impurities.

- Either such serial are misguiding us or they have done thorough research better than us. *

Comment: Are you sure that it's 16 impurities and not 12?

Comment: yeah 16 impurities.

Comment: Oh the impurities of the body only or those of even mind and soul? Do u have any links where u have found this?

Comment: @Rickross I heard via mouth and second I saw it in tv series, Devon Ke Dev Mahadev, season 4 episodes I am looking for a person to sue them for misinformation.

Comment: Oh don't know in what context it was said but I know about the 12 impurities of the body as the Manu verse says.

Comment: the context was used when parvati desired to get the lord shiva as husband, then shiv told narad she is impure as she is human, I can not accept her as my wife, as she posses 16 impurities.Hope now it clears @Rickross

Comment: Oh then it might be said about the 12 impurities only which I have talked about in the answer. But we can't be 100% sure too so please wait for more answers.

Comment: There is possibly no 16 impurities. I have chkd some other scriptures as well. It's only 12 impurities for the human body.

Comment: @Rickross Source: TV serial devon-ke-dev-mahadev Chapter 4 Episode 162 at 7:00  where narad tells parvati to get rid of 16 impurities. Now either director and writer misinterpreted our scriptures or they have thoroughly researched on this.

Comment: Hmm not sure probably they are wrong. I have searched all the Smritis as well as the 108 Upanishads. Nothing found on the 16 impurities in those.

Comment: In the same context of getting cleansed and purified so that She could get Him. I request you to watch those clips.

Comment: Ok so  will I get those clips on Youtube?

Comment: such question I dont expect, you can see it on google hotstar or google. Try.

Answer (score 8):

A partial answer ...

There are actually only 12 impurities of a human body.

Blood, tears, ear wax, phlegm, sweat, urine etc are considered as the 12 impurities of the human body as per Manu Smriti.

See the following verses:

> Manu Smriti 5.134. In order to cleanse (the organs) by which urine and
>   faeces are ejected, earth and water must be used, as they may be
>   required, likewise in removing the (remaining ones among) **twelve
>   impurities of the body**
>
> Manu smriti 5.135. Oily exudations, semen, blood, (the fatty substance
>   of the) brain, urine, faeces, the mucus of the nose, ear-wax, phlegm,
>   tears, the rheum of the eyes, and sweat **are the twelve impurities of
>   human (bodies).**

Now, from [this page](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200518.html) we get the commentary of Medhatithi on 5.135 (mentioned as 5.133 in the linked page). From there we also get to know about a similar verse found in Vishnu Smriti.

> Viṣṇu (22.81).—‘Adeps, semen, blood, dandruff, urine, faeces, ear-wax,
>   nail-parings, phlegm, tears, rheum, and sweat are the **twelve impure
>   excretions** from the body.’

And, Atri Smriti too has a similar verse:

> Fat, semen, blood, marrow, urine, excreta, dirt of the ears, nails,
>   phlegm, bones, dirt of the eye, and drops of perspiration, these
>   twelve are the dirts of men.
>
> **Atri Smriti 1.31**

Comment: what's difference between mucus and phelgm ? what's fatty substance of brain ?

Comment: See the Sanskrit words used in the original from here: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200518.html @ram

Comment: @UdayKrishna Blood is considered impure only when it comes in touch with the sense organ of touch i.e skin. Blood can not be considered impure when it's flowing in the veins. Because otherwise the body can not ever be made pure. So, if there's a cut and blood oozes out only then it is impure to touch.

Comment: As per medical science, blood is becoming impure, all the time..due to air pollution, infections, climate changes etc etc.That was my point.Could have bettered ny communication, by using, the term medical science..in the first instance!