# Do gods have 12 impurities (aśhuddhis)?

Tags: body, devatas

Human body is said to have 12 impurities, as discussed in [this QnA](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28796/what-are-the-16-impurities-ashuddhi-in-a-human-body).

What about gods? As discussed in one of the answer in [this QnA](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19814/why-do-the-gods-look-like-human-beings), God created the humans in his image. So, do gods also possess these 12 impurities similar to humans?

Comment: First off, "God" is a phenomenon and not a "being" that too a physical being. And Deities are not the same as "God" the phenomenon. Deities are abstractions that can be realized within us. So to avoid misinterpretations it is better to stick to Sanskrit terms such as - Bhagawan and Devata etc. 

Since you talk about Gods, I presume Devatas here. No - since they are energies, they are definitely not subject to the impurities that you list. They are realities that can be observed in the state of Turiya. Hence Turiya is listed as the state of Gods.

Comment: You can show reference and proofs plz

Comment: You told that gods definitely not subject To impurities . brother plz prove with reference

Comment: Please read Talk 30, Talk 617 (page 599) in this link - https://selfdefinition.org/ramana/Talks-with-Sri-Ramana-Maharshi--complete.pdf.  That is the nearest I could find which clearly indicate that deities are not physical beings.  PS: In my comment above the sentence must read "They are realities that can be observed."

Comment: Plz give reference form Hindu scripture

Comment: In Shiva Purana kumaraswamy born form semen of lord Shiva

Comment: Semen is impurity .

Comment: You are mixing two entirely different things - the Smriti (remembrances) and Shruti. Puranas are personified imagery meant for kids just like the Panchatantra which was a personified imagery of the Niti Shastra. What I quoted above was a direct Yogic insight into reality. So I leave it up to you to decide whether you want stories OR the unvarnished reality.

Comment: You are telling that puranas are myth ond stories

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124558/discussion-between-siv-and-pasham-vishnu-vardhan-goud).

Comment: may puranas are myth . but itihasas are history and real . I want to know that itihasa Ramayana tells about kurmaraswamy birth form semen of Shiva.  According to you devatas do not have impurities like semen . but history is telling that Shiva as semen means impurity